# Android ExpandableListActivity and TabActivity in same Class

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to use the ExpandableListActivity in my program but I have already inherited the TabActivity in my class. I cannot do multiple inheritance and I need to use both the ExpandableListView and the Tabs in my program.
I checked Google's code for the ExpandableListView here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html.

But here they are inheriting the ExpandableListActivity which I cannot do as I have already inherited TabActivity in my class.

I am aware that I can use ListView without inheriting ListActivity in my class. Can I do the same for the ExpandableListView class also ? If so, then can anyone please provide me with any sample code to use ExtendableListView without inheriting the activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a custom view that extends ExpandableListView and use it inside the TabActivity.

Expandable List View

```
  public class CustomExpListView extends ExpandableListView{
          /** Your code **/
     }
```

Main Activity that hosts the tabs

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity{
    private TabHost tabhost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          tabHost = getTabHost();
          tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab 1")
                .setIndicator("Tab 1",
                        this.getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.tab_icon))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1.class)));

      /** Further code**/
    }
  }
```

XML Layout file for the tab with the exp list (Tab 1)

```
/**Other layout stuff goes here**/
<com.jmango.nexus.view.ProductListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:childIndicator="@drawable/child_indicator"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
                    android:divider="#00BBFF"
                    android:childDivider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:id="@+id/exp_list_view"/>
```

In the class for the tab with the exp list

```
CustomExpListView custExpListView = (CustomExpListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.exp_list_view);
```

You can also extend the listeners and customize it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how do I set the adapters for the ExpList ?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I resolved it using your idea. Works like a charm now. Thanks again.